# How to fail Velocity template processing with tracable message

Tags: velocity, maven-site-plugin

Having:

- Velocity template or macro
- some object

How to validate the object (*#if*) and fail (stop further processing) in a way that is easily tracable to the place of failure (like throwing exception in Java).

I am looking for something like this:

```
#if ( ! $context.treasureMap.containsKey('gold'))
  #fail('no golden treasure here')
#end
```

**Background**

I am writing a maven site page. The velocity context is injected by maven and contains POM information. I want to test existence of some information from effective pom. When the information is not available, I want to fail.

**Requirements**

- fail Velocity processing > fail site generation > fail maven build.
- error message should lead to the place of failure so the site should be fixed
- preferably no configuration (no extensions, just constructs/tools contained in plain Velocity)

**Tried**

- Strict Reference Mode
  Unwanted configuration, do not want to fail on every occasion.
- `#evaluate('#end')` aka syntax error
  (Chose `#end` as most descriptive to my intent) Basically what I want. Fails the processing and maven build but the error message does not lead back to failure location:
  `ParseException: Encountered "#end" at line 1, column 1.`.

Comment: To at least show the error line/column in maven build I found that the information from Velocity exception is not used in doxia-site-renderer artifact. I reported an issue [DOXIASITETOOLS-179](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DOXIASITETOOLS-179)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a method call which produce exception.See [explanation](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.4/ymtd/ymtd-error-handling.html):

> The only place where one could run into trouble within Velocity is if there is a call to a method which throws an exception during runtime. For example, this VTL defines a String $foo and then attempts to call its substring() method on it would throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException:

```
 #set ($foo = "bar")

  #set ($bar = $foo.substring(0,10))
```

> When the exception is thrown, the parser will stop processing and throw that exception up the stack tree where it can be caught in the method that caused the parser to execute. At that point, the exception can be handled gracefully.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for something like this, but the error message is not that helpfull "Error getting a parser for testpage.vm"

Comment: But you have the line failed and description. For user defined exception see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659200/how-to-throw-an-user-defined-exception-from-velocity-template-script-vtl

Comment: I cannot see line or column anywhere - generated page is blank and maven shows just the information I quoted.

Comment: I do not use velocity from Java and therefore cannot modify the context from Java (to register handlers etc). The velocity is handled by maven (maven-site-plugin) and my entry point is a Velocity template.

Comment: Also velocity.log is not generated (consumed by maven I guess)